# Is there how to resolve isADirectory error

Tags: python-3.x

```
standard_codes = "/root/malware/ops.txt"
app_dir = "/root/malware/decompiled/"

ef std_codes_list(standard_codes):

std_codes = []

with open(standard_codes,'r') as fp:
    for cnt, line in enumerate(fp): 
        read_lines = fp.read();
        read_lines = read_lines.split("\n")
        std_codes = read_lines
        std_codes.pop() 

return std_codes
```

and after running the whole program I am getting this error

```
IsADirectoryError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
----> 1 std_codes = std_codes_list(standard_codes)
2
3 apk_list = pickle.load(open('apk_pickle_list.pkl', 'rb'))
4
5 for each_apk in apk_list:

in std_codes_list(standard_codes)
3 std_codes = [] #empty list which will later contain all the standard op-codes read from the ops.txt file
4
----> 5 with open(standard_codes,'r') as fp:
6 for cnt, line in enumerate(fp): # reading each op-code in the txt file
7 read_lines = fp.read();

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/root/malware/ops.txt'
```

Comment: is ```/root/malware/ops.txt``` a directory or a file?  what do you get when you ```ls -l /root/malware/ops.txt```?

Comment: is /root/malware/ops.txt it is a directory that contains a file name ops.txt

Comment: then you're using the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong path since as you've mentioned that /root/malware/ops.txt is a directory.  since the actual file is "/root/malware/ops.txt/ops.txt", try the following code:

```
standard_codes = "/root/malware/ops.txt/ops.txt"
app_dir = "/root/malware/decompiled/"

ef std_codes_list(standard_codes):

std_codes = []

with open(standard_codes,'r') as fp:
    for cnt, line in enumerate(fp): 
        read_lines = fp.read();
        read_lines = read_lines.split("\n")
        std_codes = read_lines
        std_codes.pop() 

return std_codes
```